# How to integrate screen orientation lock inside ReactJS application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, orientation, mobile-website

I need to lock my ReactJS application to portrait mode.
I've tried to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock API.

I've added this piece of code inside my react application.
`var myScreenOrientation = window.screen.orientation;`

And then added this to lock my application to portrait mode.
`myScreenOrientation.lock("portrait");`

This functionality is supported in latest chrome, but when I'm testing the application on mobile it just turns blank and it doesnt display anything.

Comment: did you found a sollution for this?